# Can I store the range result of =Offset() in another cell?

Tags: excel

It's recommended to use =MATCH() in it's own cell and then use INDEX to refer to that cell.  This makes sense, why redo the MATCH() formula over and over when it's the same result?

I want to do the same thing with the OFFSET() formula.  I'm working with large tables and I understand that keeping your ranges small is the key to optimization.  So, using OFFSET to figure out how big of a range i want to use has been extremely beneficial.  However, sometimes I might have an IF statement that checks out several COUNTIFS that require the same range.  In these cells I am forced to use the OFFSET to determine the exact same range, over and over... wouldn't it be better to simply do the same thing as INDEX/MATCH?

Unfortunately I don't think excel can output the range itself... I notice in the formula auditor that it will reveal the resulting range--i need that literal range in a cell so A1 might say "$B$2:$B$342".

Probably not possible, but thought I'd ask!

Thanks

Comment: True, it's rather problematic to store that range in an actual worksheet cell, which would then require the use of INDIRECT in order to force that entry to be recognised as an actual range reference. But there's nothing stopping you defining that range as a Named Range, and referencing that in your formulas instead. Additionally, if the use of OFFSET is here being used to generate a dynamic range, I should let you know that it's almost always preferable to do this using an INDEX construction, which is only, let's say, minimally volatile compared to the full volatility of OFFSET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the 'CELL()' formula.  This formula can return the 'address' of a referenced cell.  See formula below:

```
=CELL("address",B1)&":"&CELL("address",B10)
```

Results should be: $B$1:$B$10

Put the above formula in cell 'A1' and see if this helps you at all.  You will probably need to tweak it a bit to get the exact results you're looking for (for example, you may need to 'nest' your offset() formula within the cell() formula).

Best of luck!